# Cannot create ActiveX component in inventor api

Tags: vb.net, iis, autodesk

I using Inventor api programming using vb.net.Here is my code for opening a inventor application.

```
inventorApp = CreateObject("Inventor.Application")
            inventorApp.Visible = True
            Dim oDoc As Document
            oDoc = inventorApp.Documents.Open("F:\inventor\Cube.ipt")
```

the code is working fine and open the document while debugging in  visual studio and working fine .but I trying to[image] host this web app in local IIS and try then the following error is showing.

anybody know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely a security issue.
If you want to create an ActiveX component, you have to add the permissions using dcomcnfg.exe

Take a look at George's answer:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t81423-re-vb-net-excel-automation-issue-cannot-create-activex-component.html

By the way, I would recommend using the Inventor Apprentice Library. It does most of the things Inventor does but it is much quicker.

Comment: Thanks..   Can I do all things in Inventor Apprentice Library which I done in Inventor API?

Comment: You can query most of the properties of an inventor file. You can print files and add, remove and modify file properties. Whether an operation is enabled in inventor apprentice is indicated by an icon in the [inventor api chm-file.](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1079044&siteID=123112)